# Upper bound of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+k+1}) \cdot a^n$ where $a\in (0, 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality

I need an upper bound for this quantity:
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+k+1}) \cdot a^n$ for $a \in (0,1)$ and when $k$ is an arbitrary but fixed integer.

I can get bounds which scale linearly with $k$ But it’s too loose. I tried Cauchy-Schwartz but it’s too loose as well. Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: maybe this helps https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1527778p9170518

Comment: I get $(k+1)/(a-a^2)$.

Comment: An upper bound is $-\frac{k+1}{k+2}\ln(1 - a)$.

Comment: To be clear, you're talking about the function $$ \Big(1-\frac{1}{a^{k+1}}\Big)\ln\Big(\frac{1}{1-a}\Big)+\frac{1}{a^k}+\frac{1}{2a^{k-1}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{k+1}. $$

Comment: @runway44 Nice. How did you get that?

Comment: @RiverLi Split the sum into two, then notice each is a Newton-Mercator series (but the second is truncated and the powers are shifted).

Comment: @runway44 I see. Thanks.